# Still unable to align floating divs after checking previous posts?

Tags: html, css

Checked previous posts but still unable to find the problem - previously had 3 divs, all  floated left and aligned perfectly after factoring in borders/padding/margins.

Now I'm trying to do a simple layout change (2 divs / float left - side by side) but can't get the 2nd div to align next to the first one, not sure what's wrong. Checked for missed closing tags, etc. but see nothing that would cause this.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated! The HTML, CSS, & JS for what is right now a non-working calculator are included below, not sure if they're going to show up correctly.

**HTML**

```
<h2>What is General Services?</h2>
<div class="d1gs">
   The District 1 Committee of Alcoholics Anonymous is a service body for the groups in         
   District 1. It is comprised of the groups' General Service Representatives (GSR's),     
   District ...
</div>
<br>
<div class="d1gs">
   Its primary purpose is to provide a forum for sharing collective 12th Step experience 
   how best to carry the AA message in the Pinellas County area. The District also has   
   responsibility ...
</div>
<br>
<div class="d1gs">
   District 1 is supported by the voluntary contributions of the groups it serves. The     
   District One Committee structure borrows much from "The AA Service Manual and Twelve 
   Concepts ...
</div>
<br>

<!-- begin.column2 -->
<div id="column2">
   <div id="center"><strong>Sobriety Calculator</strong></div>
   <em><small>
      Every alcoholic who has been graced with the gift of sobriety is a miracle
      please use the calculator below to find out how long you've enjoyed your new found 
      freedom… 
   </small></em>
   <div class="center" style="height: 5px;"><small><strong>RIGHT DOWN TO THE SECOND! 
   </strong></small></div>
   <form id="live" class="center" name="live">
      <small>Sober Date: (i.e. <span style="font-style: italic;">May 28, 1995</span>)</small>
      <input type="text" name="age" size="18" />
      <input onclick="sobertimer(this.form)" type="button" name="start" value="Click Here" /> 
      <input type="reset" name="resetb" value="Reset" />
      <label><small>Sober Days</small> </label> <br><input type="text" name="time3" size="12" />
      <label><small>Sober Hours</small> </label> <br><input type="text" name="time2" size="12" />
      <label><small>Sober Minutes</small></label> <br><input type="text" name="time1" size="12" />
      <label><small><em><strong>SOBER HEARTBEATS!</strong></em></small></label><br>
      <input type="text" name="time4" size="12" />
  </form>
</div>
<!-- end .column2 -->
```

**CSS**

```
/* What is District 1 General Services?
-------------------------------------------------------------- */
.d1gs { 
  font-family: 'Georgia', 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  float: left;
  width: 55%;
  margin-bottom: 1.5%;
  margin-top: .5%;
  margin-left: .35%;
  padding: 1% 0 1% 2%;
}

/* Sobriety Calculator
-------------------------------------------------------------- */
#column2 {
  font-family: 'Georgia', 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: .5em;
  font: 80%/1.4 Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  margin-bottom: 1.5%;
  margin-left: .35%;
  padding: .5%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.3);
  border-style: inset;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: #B2B200;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="mce-text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
function sobertimer() { 
  today = new Date(); SoberDay = new
  Date(document.live.age.value); timeold = (today.getTime() - SoberDay.getTime()); 
  sectimeold = timeold / 1000; secondsold = Math.floor(sectimeold); msPerDay = 
  24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; timeold = (today.getTime() - SoberDay.getTime()); 
  e_daysold = timeold / msPerDay; daysold = Math.floor(e_daysold); e_hrsold = 
  (e_daysold - daysold) * 24; hrsold = Math.floor(e_hrsold); minsold =   
  Math.floor((e_hrsold - hrsold) * 60); document.live.time4.value = secondsold;  
  document.live.time3.value = daysold;  document.live.time2.value = hrsold; 
  document.live.time1.value = minsold; timerID = setTimeout("sobertimer()", 1000); 
}
// ]]></script>
```

Comment: P.S.- not sure if I can do a screen shot or not, but have that available if it's possible to add that. Thanks...

Comment: You can add screenshots. Upload them to Picasa or something, then just use the image button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand now you want two columns ... so make it enclose your three initial divs in a `<div id="column1>"` and make it float to the left with a fixed width. Then make your `column2` float to the right with the restant width.

*Take care on the widths with the padding, margin and border.

See this Fiddle and tell me if that's what you want http://jsfiddle.net/pGSAR/6/

Comment: Thanks, Danko, but I should clarify just a bit, sorry if I didn't explain it better initially. The 3 floating divs I had previously are no longer part of the layout; however, one of them I now wanted to move up to float alongside some text rather than having a floating boxes. Tried to add an image to better explain but I don't have a good enough reputation! I did try enclosing the 2 divs into another div and that didn't work...

Comment: Danko, so sorry for not checking the JSFiddle link before replying! That's exactly what I want - need to check the coding to see exactly what was changed & where I went wrong, but thanks so much for your help! FYI: can't vote your answer up either since I don't have a good enough reputation here yet - but that answer was PERFECT!

Comment: Thanks, man, much appreciated and looks good - just needs tweaking for appearances. Just can't figure out why I was able to float 3 boxes side by side with NO PROBLEMS, and then I run into this problem and couldn't see the issue for close to 2 hours!  :)